# Deploy JSF-Maven application from Eclipse directly to tomcat

Tags: jsf, svn, maven, tomcat

Well, i have doubts about best practice to do a deploy correctly. So, lets go.

I have a project JSF with Maven in my local machine in ECLIPSE IDE. In other side (my server online) i have a Tomcat Server (version 6) + SVN Server working normally. The communication from my Eclipse with SVN Repository works fine. My doubt is about putting WAR file from my eclipse workspace to tomcat webapp folder, so i have some solutions to do this:

A) This is the most simple form but i don't know if this correct (best practice): Make a Maven Build (in ECLIPSE) and i'll have a WAR file. Copy the WAR file manually to tomcat webapp folder.

B) Make a "svn checkout" in my "SERVER ONLINE" (where is locate my svn server) and after i can make "mvn tomcat:deploy" to generate WAR file, and copy to tomcat webapp folder.

C) I think this form is more correct but i don't know how can i do: From my ECLIPSE IDE directly deploy (create WAR file) in TOMCAT Remote Server (webapp remote folder).

D) Open "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/manager/html" and put manually the WAR file.

Well, this is the first time i'm doing this, and i need know what is the most used form.

Answer (score 1):

I and heard most people deploy by **A C D** way.
You can do it manually without Eclipse see [here](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat/)

Comment: The option A and D i know how to do, but the option "C" i don't know how can i do it.
I saw the tutorial from "myKong" in the link, but how can i make a "mvn tomcat:deploy" inside eclipse ?